# Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php7

Tags: php, ubuntu, installation

I tried installing php in ubuntu 16.04 using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json php7.0-cgi  php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7
```

but it says

> Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php7

Should I skip this or install by an alternative way?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The name of the package is `libapache2-mod-php7.0`
Try again by having that `.0` at the end and it should work.

Comment: It's Working Great Thanks

Answer (score 25):

On Ubuntu 18.04, I had to add the repository below first. Once the repo was added I was able to install the php7.x items.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Source: https://websiteforstudents.com/apache2-with-php-7-1-support-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-beta-server/

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Ubuntu 17.04/17.10 or above use php7.1 instead of 7.0 since it is no longer available.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1
```

Answer (score 4):

At the time of the post Ubuntu 16.04 was one of the newer versions and as such the packages changed to php7.0 but as time goes on it will be 7.1 to 7.2 etc... and I don't have the time to figure out what was the latest package and I'm not dependent on a specific version. 
So if you want the latest version of packages to install without having to know the correct version number just drop the version number and the latest applicable to the distribution you are using will be installed. 
In my case I was using Ubuntu 17.10 and the php version is different so I used the following command line to get the latest.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php-mysql libapache2-mod-php mysql-server
```

It installed php 7.1 and all of the correct dependencies.

So if you don't require a specific version but just want the latest that works with the distribution drop the version number and use the command line above.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely the case that your local package index is not updated; try

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then run the previous command again.

As an aside, there is now a program `apt` that is supposedly more user-friendly than `apt-get`, `apt-cache` etc. (see [this question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get)). So your commands could have been replaced by

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install <the packages>
```

to get a slightly nicer user interface.

Probably this question would have been better suited to the [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) community.

Answer (score 1):

just test upper versions of php
for example run:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-mysql php7.4-curl php7.4-json php7.4-cgi  php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache server can't start because libapache2-mod-php7.0 is not installed:
by default aptitude or apt install php7.0-common version 7.8.13 which is not adaptable and libapache2-mod-php need 7.0.8

1. remove php-common
2. download http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php7.0-common deb package and install it if it compains about php7.0-json, readline,cli,opache
   then seatch in upper textbox  about those library and install them in this manner
3. json
4. opach
5. cli
6. readline
7. install libapache2-mod-php7.0
   RESTART APACHE 2
   service apache2 restart

it must working probably
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try for Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql <other packages>;
```

for Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql php5-mysql <other packages>;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

> sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.1
```

worked for me (16.04Ubuntu).

Comment: updated php version,                                                                                           
sudo apt install php7.2-mysql php7.2-curl php7.2-json php7.2-cgi  php7.2 libapache2-mod-php7.2

Answer (score 0):

If you getting error like `php7.2`  `php7.2-curl` `libapache2-mod-php` doesn't have installable candidate or not locate any package or dependencies is `php7.2-common` Or `libcurl3` Do this . Remeber Change your package name as per your requirements

You have to tackle in mature way. Install aptitude these ubuntu package manager will finds all dependencies, and will install one by one.

```
apt-get install aptitude
```

Now you have to check if aptitude can download it or not if download it follow instructions

```
sudo aptitude install php7.2-curl
```

If you have gotten any error like this

```html
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-curl
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-curl'
```

Any type on error i'm not talking about proper these errors

Try to add php package again

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt-get update
```

Now try this command

```
sudo aptitude install php7.2-curl
```

Aptitude will ask you you want to keep current version of all dependencies

```html
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     php7.2-curl [Not Installed]                        



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Type `n` then `Enter`

Aptitude will find all dependencies and ask you to install all package type

```
y
```

Again

```
y
```

Then

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

For centos of rhel

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

It will Not enabling PHP 7.2 FPM by default.
NOTICE: To enable PHP 7.2 FPM in Apache2 do

```
a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif

a2enconf php7.2-fpm
```

This method is not only for this error you can find any of php apache2 or ubuntu system package solution using aptitude.

```
Upvote if you find your solution
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we need to install the same version of libapache2-mod-php as the version of php present .I had php 7.4 installing libapache2-mod-php7.4 solved the problem.Thanks